# Datatable jquery keys up and down

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I want to include the management of keys and click on my datatable... I try with "keys:true" but idk why it doesn't work.

so I try

```
$('#example').on('click', 'tr', function () {

    let table = $('#example').DataTable();
    var tr = $(this);

    if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
        $(this).removeClass('selected');
    }
    else {
        $('#example').DataTable().$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    }

    $(document).keydown(function (e) {

        if (e.keyCode == 40) { //arrow down

            table.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
            tr.next().addClass('selected');
            tr = table.$('tr.selected');

        }
        if (e.keyCode == 38) { //arrow up
            table.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
            tr.prev().addClass('selected');
            tr = table.$('tr.selected');

        }
    })  

});
```

I have 3 problems

- when i launch the table the first row is never selected
- if i'm in the first row and i press key up the focus disappear
- i have to click to select the row...there's a way to go on the first row also with the key down?

Comment: `if ($('tr.selected').length === 0) $("tr").first().addClass("selected")`

Comment: check this code and try like the same. hope it will work: https://datatables.net/extensions/keytable/examples/initialisation/simple.html

Comment: "keys:true" doesn't work on my table